# In wordpress I am trying to modify the CSS of search button and changes not taking effect

Tags: css, wordpress

[Inspect PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG8hJ.jpg) When for debugging reason I am Inspecting in browser I am seeing the css code I have in my custom.css and if I change anything there it's taking effect. But
when I get into editor and change the code it's not taking effect.

MY code for search button:

```
 input[type="submit"],
    button[type="submit"] {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.33;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

I have used 
`<?php get_search_form(); ?>` 
in my header.php.

How to change the style of search and Submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provided enough information but if you see the change reflected in your custom.css, then I imagine the value you are setting is being overridden by other selector.

I suggest you take a look at resource such as https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ which covers CSS specificity.

If you update your question with a screen shot of the inspector showing the target button, I can take a look and see if I can determine anything (if the site is public, I could take a look directly assuming it's SFW.

**Update**: Thanks for the screenshot. So, I took a look and the styles you posted are all coming from  style.css. I suspect your file either isn't being included or perhaps read (no link to the css in the html). Perhaps it's not in the right spot in the server? Or it's not updated on the server? There are quite a few possibilities for this....

Comment: Thanks for helping @Frank
 you can see the pic in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put a `<div class="searchform">` around the form to ensure that only this form will be changed.

Comment: Hi @meck thanks for the answer. The problem is when in browser by going into inspect mode and changing the values the changes takes effect
But inside code editor it doesn't. now I don't understand your answer please explain

Comment: @Ani when you change the CSS via the inspector, the style gets added to the element inline, thus with the highest priority. Your actual CSS doesn't get added that way and is probably being overriden by more specific selectors.